# a(a+1)...(a+n-1) PHP

Tags: php, циклы

a(a+1)...(a+n-1)
Требуется вывести результат последовательности.
Задание из лабы по паскалю. Туплю.

Решил задачу, спасибо

```
Var m, a, i, n: integer;
Begin
//a(a+1)...(a+n)
    read(a,n);
    m:=a;
    i:=1;
 While i<n do
       Begin
            m:=m*(a+i);
            Inc(i);
       End;
 writeln('ans=',m);
```

End.

Comment: чтобы ваш вопрос не закрыли, приведите код, как вы пытались решить задачу. ибо пока что это не "туплю" а "решите за меня"

Comment: что тут тупить вообще `for($i=0;$i<n;$i++){ $result *= ($a + $i);}`

Comment: Лаба по паскалю, поэтому не предоставил. А пишу сюда потому что трэд оживленный.

Comment: Какое отношение имеет лаба по паскалю к PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mul = $a;
for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++)
  $mul *= $a + $i;
echo $mul;
```

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется, что эта задача имеет интерес, если например решать ее одной строкой

```
$a = 2;
$n = 3;
echo array_reduce(range(0, $n - 1), function($r, $v) use ($a){ return $r*($a+$v);}, 1);
```

или

```
echo array_product(array_map(function($v) use ($a){ return $a + $v; }, range(0, $n-1)));
```